# Как выбрать одно случайное число из двух диапазонов?

Tags: delphi, случайные-числа

Есть диапазон чисел, допустим "1 .. n", и есть второй диапазон чисел, допустим "2n .. 3n". Хочу реализовать выборку одного случайного значения из этих двух диапазонов чисел.
Своего рода что-то наподобие:

```
r:=RandomRange(RandomRange(1, 10), RandomRange(1000, 2000));
```

Но ведь так `RandomRange` здесь с задаче не справится.
Т.е. В данном примере, в сгенерированных случайных числах, будут исключены числа диапазона от 11 од 999.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так:

```
r:=RandomRange(1,1010);
if r>=10 then r:=r+990;
```

upd.

1. Всего чисел в обоих диапазонах 1009. (от 1 до 9, и от 1000 до 1999).
2. Берем рандомное число от 1 до 1010 - как раз 1009 чисел.
3. Если попали в первый диапазон, то все ок, если вышли из первого диапазона, значит попали во второй.
4. Аналогично можно выбирать из трех и более с массивом и циклом. Для двух достаточно двух строк, см. выше.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, гениально и просто.

Answer (score 2):

Для получения равновероятных результатов из 2 и более диапазонов, сделайте так:

1. Подсчитайте "ширину" каждого диапазона (`9, 1000`)
2. Сложите диапазоны вместе один за другим - для каждого диапазона сохраните его начало, конец и оригинальное начало (получится массив типа `[0,9,1], [10,1009,1000]`)
3. Выберите случайное число от 0 до максимального (конец последнего диапазона + 1) (`Random(1010)`)
4. Определите в какой диапазон попало число (в цикле пройдите по массиву проверяя входит ли число в границы) (например `768` попадает во 2 диапазон)
5. Отнимите от числа начало диапазона и добавьте начало оригинального диапазона (`768 - 10 + 1000`)
6. Готово